# Android Studio (Gradle) cannot find Mockito

Tags: android-studio, mockito

I try to use Mockito from within Android Studio 1.2.2 but I get the following error:

> Error:(50, 17) Failed to resolve: org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19

The error occurs when I sync Gradle after adding the dependency manually. This is the dependency in my module Gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19' 
}
```

Could anyone help my resolve this issue?

Related questions:

1. Do I first need to download Mockito manually?
2. If so, where should I put it?

Note: the comments were helpfull to solve the above problem. However, it got me into another problem which I could not solve. But updating to Android Studio 1.3 solved it. I am now running Mockito from within Android Studio.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try replacing `testCompile` with `androidTestCompile`, it works for me when importing Mockito libs.

However, you may run to a runtime error if you include only mockito-core. You'll need to add into your gradle:

```
androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2"
androidTestCompile "com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.2"
```

If you have error with dexcache, put this line into your `setUp()` (Assuming you are using `InstrumentalTestCase`)

```java
System.setProperty("dexmaker.dexcache", getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getCacheDir().getPath());
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, it didn't help. Same error keeps popping up. Actually, I also added the dexcache lines. Now the error comes up 3 times. Do I need to download those packages first? Where should I put them?

Comment: Probably your gradle is on offline work mode. Go to File/Settings/Gradle and see if "Offline work" checked, uncheck it and sync again.

Comment: I switched the `Offline work` on and off just to check. Now I get this meesage:

`...':app:_debugAndroidTestCompile'.
   > Could not resolve org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19
     Required by:...
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/mockito-core-1.10.19.pom'.`

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, look like mockito is a lib of maven. So try adding this
    `repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }`
right before the dependencies block and sync again.

Comment: Now I get connection refused for jcenter, mavenCentral and bintray. So I guess repository/dependencies work but I need to check my proxy settings.

Comment: Did not find any solution. But since the recent update to Android Studio 1.3 it all of the sudden works.

Comment: Converting testCompile to androidTestCompile worked for me. Thanks!!!

Comment: @HoangPhan thx! that worked was in offline mode, i suspected this might be the case because I didn't see the libs in `External Libraries` in the Project view

Answer (score 1):

I was stuck into a similar problem, and adding the mockito jar file manually did the thing for me.

To do that, first create a directory called "libs" in your app directory. Take note that this directory should be in the same level as that of the src/main and build directories.
Next, download the mockito jar file and paste it into the libs directory.

Include that into your dependencies in the app level build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/add-your-jar-file-name-here')
}
```

Sync the gradle and that should do the job.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library/18321935#18321935) answer for more detailed answer with snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

androidTestCompile has now been replaced with androidTestImplementation

```
dependencies {

androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the test file is located under `$your_module/src/test/java` or `$your_module/src/androidTest/java` directory.