# Why can't gradle find com.google.dexmaker?

Tags: android, maven, android-layout, gradle, dexmaker

Currently work on a fork of https://github.com/lucasr/probe. Just getting into the start, but for some reason, when I try to build it I get this error quite a few times:

```
/Users/me/probe/library/src/main/java/org/lucasr/probe/DexProxyBuilder.java:27: error: package com.google.dexmaker does not exist
import com.google.dexmaker.Code;
```

I don't really know how it is going wrong, since the build.gradle for the library project has:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
}
```

Edit: Full `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.2'
}

apply from: "${rootDir}/gradle/scripts/gradle-mvn-push.gradle"

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                pom.whenConfigured {
                    def dep = dependencies.find { it.groupId == 'com.google.dexmaker' }
                    dep.optional = true
                    dep.scope = null
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your complete `build.gradle` file.

Comment: Looking at this closely related discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219624/android-studio-gradle-cannot-find-mockito), I think you may also have to change `compile` to  `androidTestCompile`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work to change it to androidTestCompile, probably because it is used outside of the tests in the project.

Answer (score 0):

dexmaker Github says:

**Gradle users can import the project this way:**

```
testCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.4"
testCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-dx:1.4"
testCompile "com.crittercism.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.4"
```