# cannot resolve MockitoJUnitRunner

Tags: android, mockito

I use gradle with my android project. The sdk version is 24 but with the 23 i have the same problem. I put

```
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'

jcenter()
```

And the imports related to are not resolved. But AndroidJUnit4 is resolved

[to see the problem click here][1]
(with or without static it doesn't change)

my gradle files :
[gradle1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFiHO.png)
[gradle2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qaUeN.png)

Thank you

Comment: have you add `testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'` ??

Comment: yes i have, i think everything i should add is added. But doesn't work.

Comment: sry but doesn't work better, i will make capture of every gradle file in the post above

Comment: This could be the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219624/android-studio-gradle-cannot-find-mockito

Answer (score 0):

use Mockito 2.x

testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.0'